# emails to root - CentOS and Postfix permssion error on maildir file

Tags: centos, email, postfix, permissions, email-server

I'm trying to setup a new mail relay server to send email out from internal servers only over TLS. I've followed this guide http://www.krizna.com/centos/setup-mail-server-centos-7/ to Step 10. I only need to send email not receive.

Anyways I keep getting the following error and cannot figure out how to correct the permissions issue on roots mail folder.

Any ideas? Thanks in advanced!

Error:

```
Sep 25 11:38:39 mx postfix/local[2894]: warning: perhaps you need to create the maildirs in advance
Sep 25 11:38:39 mx postfix/local[2894]: C16AA4BE1A: to=<root@mydomain.net>, orig_to=<postmaster>, relay=local, delay=0.06, delays=0.03/0.01/0/0.02, dsn=5.2.0, status=bounced (maildir delivery failed: create maildir file /root/mail/tmp/1443199119.P2894.mx.mydomain.com: Permission denied)
Sep 25 11:38:39 mx postfix/bounce[2895]: warning: C16AA4BE1A: undeliverable postmaster notification discarded
Sep 25 11:38:39 mx postfix/qmgr[2806]: C16AA4BE1A: removed
Sep 25 11:38:45 mx postfix/submission/smtpd[2888]: connect from mydesktop.mydomain.local[192.168.1.180]
Sep 25 11:38:45 mx postfix/submission/smtpd[2888]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mydesktop.mydomain.local[192.168.1.180]: 554 5.7.1 <mygmail@gmail.com>: Recipient address rejected: Access denied; from=<me@mydomain.com> to=<mygmail@gmail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<ops-001>
Sep 25 11:38:45 mx postfix/submission/smtpd[2888]: disconnect from mydesktop.mydomain.local[192.168.1.180]
```

Comment: For outgoing server, you don't postfix and its complexities. Try ssmtp instead  http://linux.die.net/man/8/ssmtp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Handling emails to `root`

You **SHOULD** use [aliases](http://www.postfix.org/aliases.5.html) to redirect emails to `root` to normal (non privileged) OS user mailbox.
[ It is **very strong** SHOULD but you may use other means to redirect]

As general rule:
Do as little as possible with root privileges.
Do not require root privileges when it is not necessary (for security reasons).